# Python - Flipping 2 characters of each word in a sentence

Tags: python, python-2.7

My function randomly flips 2 characters of a word besides the first and last character. I want to use this function to write another function `build_sentence(string)` that uses my function to flip 2 characters of each word in the sentence. The function `build_sentence(string)` should return a string containing the full sentence where the letters of each word have been scrambled by `scrambled(word)`.

for example:

```
I dn'ot gvie a dman for a man taht can olny sepll a wrod one way. (Mrak Taiwn)
```

```html
import random 

def scramble(word):
    i = random.randint(1, len(word) - 2)
    j = random.randint(1, len(word) - 3)
    if j >= i:
        j += 1

    if j < i:
        i, j = j, i

    return word[:i] + word[j] + word[i + 1:j] + word[i] + word[j + 1:]

def main():
    word = scramble(raw_input("Please enter a word: "))
    print (word)
    
main()
```

Comment: your logic currently seems incomplete, what if the user enters a 3 letter word, why do you add 1 to `j` if it's greater that `i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're happy with your current word scrambling function (with a small change so it doesn't error on words with 3 or fewer letters):

```
import random

def Scramble(word):
    if len(word) > 3:
        i = random.randint(1, len(word) - 2)
        j = random.randint(1, len(word) - 3)
        if j >= i:
            j += 1

        if j < i:
            i, j = j, i

        return word[:i] + word[j] + word[i + 1:j] + word[i] + word[j + 1:]
    else:
        return word

def ScrambleSentence(sentence):
    scrambledSentence = ""
    for word in str.split(sentence):
        print(scrambledSentence + "\n")
        scrambledSentence += Scramble(word) + " "
    return scrambledSentence.strip()

def main():
    sentence = ScrambleSentence(input("Please enter a sentence: "))
    print (sentence)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
' '.join(scramble(word) for word in phrase.split(' '))
```